# Print an external page without opening it not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I'm trying to print a PDF document without opening it. I found a [guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Printing#print_an_external_page_without_opening_it) on MDN that explains how this can be done.

```
  const handleClick = (
    event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>,
  ) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();

    const frame = document.createElement('iframe');

    frame.onload = () => {
      frame.contentWindow.print();
    };
    // frame.style.display = 'none';
    frame.src = docflow.primaryDocumentPdfUrl;
    document.body.appendChild(frame);
  };
```

In Chrome everything works well, but in Firefox an error occurs (see below).

> Partitioned cookie or storage access was provided to
> “http://localhost:3000/api/documents/5bf1c493-b8ce-4f82-9ee0-def28065c645/visualization”
> because it is loaded in the third-party context and dynamic state
> partitioning is enabled

[image]

Storage tab screenshot:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's programming question. Add some code

Comment: `display='none'` is commented out and the iframe is displayed on the page, but firefox still not work

Comment: What do you do in such cases? Are you opening another page on which `window.print()` will be called?